# create interval categories from a column including both numbers and characters in R

Tags: r, dplyr, case

Assuming I have data below, I want to add column c such that I have categories `<0, 0, 0-3, >3` if column b contains only positive or negative values otherwise category in column c would be whatever column b contains.

```
df <- data.frame(a= 1:14,
                 b= c(-1,-10,-2,0,0,2,1,4,10,12,6, "apple", "apple", "Orange"))
df 
    a      b
1   1     -1
2   2    -10
3   3     -2
4   4      0
5   5      0
6   6      2
7   7      1
8   8      4
9   9     10
10 10     12
11 11      6
12 12  apple
13 13  apple
14 14 Orange


df2
    a      b      c
1   1     -1     <0
2   2    -10     <0
3   3     -2     <0
4   4      0      0
5   5      0      0
6   6      2    0-3
7   7      1    0-3
8   8      4     >3
9   9     10     >3
10 10     12     >3
11 11      6     >3
12 12  apple  apple
13 13  apple  apple
14 14 Orange Orange
```

I am trying to apply `case_when` and `cut`. I am getting the result I need. I would appreciate any help and hint with it.

```
df %>%
mutate(c = case_when( b %in% grepl("apple|orange", b) ~ b),
                      TRUE ~ cut(as.numeric(b),
                                                       breaks = c(-999, 0, 1, 4, 999),
                                                       labels = c("<0", "0", "0-3", ">3"),
                                                       right = F))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be better to subset the numeric from the non-numeric and do it separately.  In `base R`, we can do the assignment twice on each of the subset

```
i1 <- grepl("^-?[0-9]+$", df$b)
df$c[i1] <- as.character(cut(as.numeric(df$b[i1]), 
   breaks = c(-999, 0, 1, 4, 999), labels = c("<0", "0", "0-3", ">3"), right = FALSE))
df$c[!i1] <- df$b[!i1]
```

-output

```
> df
    a      b      c
1   1     -1     <0
2   2    -10     <0
3   3     -2     <0
4   4      0      0
5   5      0      0
6   6      2    0-3
7   7      1    0-3
8   8      4     >3
9   9     10     >3
10 10     12     >3
11 11      6     >3
12 12  apple  apple
13 13  apple  apple
14 14 Orange Orange
```

---

If we want to use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
mutate(c = coalesce(case_when( !grepl("apple|orange", b)  ~ as.character(cut(as.numeric(b),
                                                       breaks = c(-999, 0, 1, 4, 999),
                                                       labels = c("<0", "0", "0-3", ">3"),
                                                       right = FALSE))), b))
```

-output

```
  a      b      c
1   1     -1     <0
2   2    -10     <0
3   3     -2     <0
4   4      0      0
5   5      0      0
6   6      2    0-3
7   7      1    0-3
8   8      4     >3
9   9     10     >3
10 10     12     >3
11 11      6     >3
12 12  apple  apple
13 13  apple  apple
14 14 Orange Orange
```

NOTE: `case_when` or `ifelse` apply the function on the whole data, so when we do `as.numeric`, the non-numeric elements are coerced to `NA`, and thus the first option got overrided.  Instead, either use `replace` or `coalesce` with `b` column after `case_when`

Comment: GREAT note to learn! thank you!